# How to pass URLs as parameters in a GET request within python flask (restplus)?

Tags: python, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I am creating a REST API using python flask. The API is ready and works on port number 8000 of my localhost. Now I intend to give this REST API a user friendly interface for which I decided to go with python - restplus. I thought of calling this service (running on 8000) internally from swagger application running on 5000

I was able to create the basic structure of the API (Swagger). The code for which looks like this:

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


@api.route('/HybridComparator/<string:url2>/<string:url1>')
class HybridComparator(Resource):
    def get(self, url1, url2):
        print(url1)
        print(url2)
        return url1 + ' ' + url2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The application as a whole runs seamlessly (with random strings as parameters) on port 5000. But when the URLs I pass are **actual links**, the application returns a response of  404 - Not found. Further to my investigation I realized the culprit being '/' embedded within the links I try to provide. Is there a way to handle URLs in particular?

Should I encode them before sending a request. (This will make my parameters look ugly). Is there something I am missing?

Comment: wont this be a problem if your parameters contain slashes?

Comment: Yes, I am facing that problem. Any known solutions ?

Comment: unfortunatly, im not aware of anything other than encoding

Comment: does [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/76/) help?

Comment: Encoding the URLs and providing them as parameters does the job. I simply have to decode them in the application using urllib. I was keen on getting a solution which does not need me to provide encoded URLs

Comment: @Nullman, I tried defining the parameter as 'path' data type instead of traditional strings. It works. But gives some weird results. I am trying to solve it using the same. Will update you as and when I have something. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

This is an entirely old question and I am sure you solved your problem by now.
But for new searchers, this may come in handy;

replace `<string:url2>/<string:url1>` with `<path:url2>/<path:url1>`

Answer (score 0):

it seems that :

```
@api.route('/HybridComparator/<path:url2>/<path:url1>')
```

should fix it ,it fixes the 404 but i am getting only "http:/" part of the param